# Is it normal for a field return by API request to be gone?

Tags: rest, api

Is it naive to expect API requests to always return a field that previously existed.
I can understand the need to introduce new fields, but is it ok to delete an entire field and without warning??

When building an app that relies on api results, how I have to safeguard against fields disappearing when a major functionality depends on result of that field?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this requires opinions to answer and might be better for the  Software Engineering StackExchange site.  But yes, if part of the results of an API are determined to be unsafe for some reason (privacy, security, server load) then they can be removed at any time.  Entire requests can be removed, for example an API might have a dumb "list all files" API that gets replaced by a version that only returns N files at a time using pagination.

Comment: For my instance, it has nothing to do with privacy, secuirty, and highly doubt it is server load since the requests also returns a load of other fields, but now I know it does happen. Thank you for the welcome and input

Answer (score 0):

It is the not normal as it is a breaking change to the clients that are already use this field. So if the API provider removes some fields without notifying you , you have no effective ways to detect it. Of course , you can always check the API return all the fields in the API response as said in the API documentation but it is very silly approach. I would simply returning some runtime exception saying that there is an unexpected system error.

Normally as an API provider , it should somehow have some strategies to manage removing fields such as :

- Notify clients that this field will be deprecated now and will be removed soon and give them some reasonable time span to update their client to migrate out of the deprecated fields.
- Monitor the field usage in production. If it is sure a field is really not used by anybody , this field can be safely removed.

Comment: Normally, yes.  But security, privacy, server stability can be more important than being nice to API consumers.  Even then I agree there should be announcements of some kind even if there's no advance warning.

Comment: yup maybe ,  but if in these cases, I would return null/empty for that fields rather than removing them .

Comment: Good point.  Returning a non-answer will break fewer clients than dropping the field completely.

Comment: It would be great if the API provider would give at least some thoughts to the API users, but i do see the points you guys make. Thx.